# How to resolve the dependency issues with npm install @types/react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a problem with `@types/react` package.

This is a small UI project that I build on top of [nextron project](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron). It used to be working fine before I had to reinstall my Windows OS.

I try to rebuild the project using `yarn` and `yarn dev`. The dependency installation goes without issues, but the `yarn dev` gives me an error:

```
# yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ nextron
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:8888, url: http://localhost:8888
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.

Please install @types/react by running:

        npm install --save-dev @types/react
```

So I follow the instruction on screen and it gives me even further error:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @naisutech/react-tree@0.4.2
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.6.0 || ^17" from next@10.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     dev next@"^10.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.3.0 || 16 || 17 || 18" from react-copy-to-clipboard@5.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-copy-to-clipboard
npm ERR!     react-copy-to-clipboard@"^5.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   23 more (react-currency-input-field, react-datepicker, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.6" from @naisutech/react-tree@0.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@naisutech/react-tree
npm ERR!   @naisutech/react-tree@"^0.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.6" from @naisutech/react-tree@0.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@naisutech/react-tree
npm ERR!     @naisutech/react-tree@"^0.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Denny\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Denny\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-21T01_20_27_399Z-debug-0.log
```

Here's what I did after that:

1. Reinstall the node.js to version 16.20.2 LTS and 18.17.1 LTS (using nvm for windows)
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` file and reinstall the whole dependencies. Nothing works so far.

After checking the error log ([here](https://pastebin.com/LDZiRaf8)). it seems there's a version conflict with my react package and what `@types/react` want.

Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@naisutech/react-tree": "^0.4.2",
    "accounting-js": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "decimal.js": "^10.3.1",
    "electron-serve": "^1.0.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next-images": "^1.7.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.10",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "puppeteer": "^15.3.2",
    "puppeteer-report": "^3.0.3",
    "randomstring": "^1.2.2",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-currency-input-field": "^3.6.4",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.1",
    "string-sanitizer": "^2.0.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.17",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^5.0.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "zustand": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "electron": "^13.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.3",
    "next": "^10.0.5",
    "nextron": "^6.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.4.8",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The JS package and its corresponding `@types/` package need to match versions, at least within a semver-major range, so if you have `react@17.0.2`, you'll need `@types/react@17` (though this isn't always perfect, it's a community effort).

You've also got a peer dependency problem though, which you can get around with `npm i --legacy-peer-deps [any other options]`. This reverts npm's behavior regarding peerdeps to how it worked in npm versions 3-6 (lockfile version 2), and will unfortunately probably be necessary for another year or two, until packages across the ecosystem either get updated or fall out of usage.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, I use this command :  `npm i --legacy-peer-deps --save-dev @types/react@17` . It still complains that I do not have the required `@types/react`

Comment: After some digging, it seems to me that whatever I do I can't fix the dependencies. When I try the newest nextron build, it run without problem. so, I think the solution would be to migrate my entire code to new nextron build.